# Gunicorn is not working on wsl (maybe due to flask_socketio)

Tags: gunicorn, flask-socketio

У меня есть проблема при запуске моего довольно простого приложения на wsl с ubuntu при помощи gunicorn. Вот мой код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, Response, session, send_file, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio_ = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route('/index', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return "HELLO, WORLD!!!"


def main():

    socketio_.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port="8001", debug=True, use_reloader=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

а вот логи ошибки:

```
[2023-11-21 17:31:52 +0600] [1891] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-11-21 17:31:52 +0600] [1891] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1891)
[2023-11-21 17:31:52 +0600] [1891] [INFO] Using worker: geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker
[2023-11-21 17:31:52 +0600] [1892] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1892
[2023-11-21 17:31:53 +0600] [1892] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 147, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/adlibuser/addlibParse/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import app
  File "/home/adlibuser/addlibParse/a.py", line 7, in <module>
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 243, in init_app
    self.server = socketio.Server(**self.server_options)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.eio = self._engineio_server_class()(**engineio_options)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._async = importlib.import_module(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/engineio/async_drivers/eventlet.py", line 3, in <module>
    from eventlet.green.threading import Event
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 79, in <module>
    setattr(dns, pkg, import_patched('dns.' + pkg))
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 61, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
    return inject(
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 109, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dns/asyncquery.py", line 38, in <module>
    from dns.query import (
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dns/query.py", line 63, in <module>
    import httpcore
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._api import request, stream
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._sync.connection_pool import ConnectionPool
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .connection import HTTPConnection
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .._synchronization import Lock
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_synchronization.py", line 13, in <module>
    import trio
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._core import TASK_STATUS_IGNORED as TASK_STATUS_IGNORED  # isort: skip
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ._local import RunVar
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_local.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import _run
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_run.py", line 2543, in <module>
    from ._io_epoll import EpollIOManager as TheIOManager
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_io_epoll.py", line 189, in <module>
    class EpollIOManager:
  File "/home/adlibuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trio/_core/_io_epoll.py", line 190, in EpollIOManager
    _epoll = attr.ib(factory=select.epoll)
AttributeError: module 'eventlet.green.select' has no attribute 'epoll'
[2023-11-21 17:31:53 +0600] [1892] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1892)
[2023-11-21 17:31:53 +0600] [1891] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1892) exited with code 3
[2023-11-21 17:31:53 +0600] [1891] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[2023-11-21 17:31:53 +0600] [1891] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

запускаю с помощью `gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 module:app`

P.S.: ошибок в названии модулей нет, но вполне возможно, что я просто что-то не учитываю при запуске.

P.S. 2.0: Пробовал запускать и другими командами gunicorn - все безуспешно, падает все та же ошибка.

P.S. 3.0: Эта же ошибка появляется, если я просто хочу запустить код с помощью `python3 module.py`